# How to reverse print stack using recursion?

Tags: c++, recursion, data-structures, stack

> *Please note that it is just reverse printing not reversing a stack*

What I want to do is with the help of recursion print the stack i.e bottom to top printing.

I have tried myself but the result is not what I expected.My code looks like this.

```
#include <bits/stdc++.h>
using namespace std;


void print(stack<char>st){
   if(st.empty()){return;}
   st.pop();
   print(st);
   cout<<st.top();
}

 int main() {
    // Assume that I have stack already made....
    print(st);
    cout<<endl;
 }
 return 0;
}
```

Would anybody mind having pointing out my mistake ? Also when I pass stack by reference the results are unexpected.Thanks for support.

Comment: What is the result and why isn't it what you expected?

Comment: Runtime error is what it is showing me.In the above implementation.Thanks for looking :) @fractalwrench

Comment: Is my algorithm right to print reverse stack ?

Comment: `stack<T>` is designed to hide its implementation. You'd have to write your own stack based on a `vector<T>`, say. You're getting an error because when you `pop` the last element, the stack is empty, then you're trying to print `st.top()` which no longer exists. Move the `cout` to before the `pop`.

Comment: Your current implementation prints top to bottom, and `stack<T>` won't support what you want. You have to write your own `MyStack` class. Also, by calling `pop` you're removing the top of the stack - you may just want to print the stack without emptying it.

Comment: @JohnD But john when we recurse..We have a copy created in the stack,don't we ? than why isn't it working ?

Comment: @JohnD Will similar things happen with list<T> also ? Like reverse printing  list(linked list) using recursion.

Comment: Sorry, missed the recursive `print(st)` in there :).  But still move `cout` above `pop`.

Comment: The answer below is right - if you store `top` you can then print it *after* the recursive call which is necessary to achieve reverse order. Sorry, didn't read your post correctly. The same principle applies for any container.

Comment: @behnc reverse-printing a `std::list<T>` using recursion would be pointless; it has a [`reverse_iterator`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/list/rbegin) implementation. Regardless, if you really intend to make copies of your reduced stack with each recursion, I suppose you can do it this way. I'd find it easier to just pass by reference. leave if empty, else save the top to tmp, pop, recurse, print tmp, push tmp, and return.

Comment: @JohnD please verify my comment on Mahedi Sabuj' answer

Comment: @behnc If you're trying to see what is inside a `stack` the *only* way is to keep calling `pop`. Only the `top` element is available to you. Each time you call `pop` the old top is removed and you can then see the element below it (which becomes the new top).   Do you mainly want to understand recursion or do you want to learn about walking through stacks, linked lists, etc?

Comment: @JohnD I am quite fine with the above mentioned topic by you.My doubt was that when I call stack again through recursion(print(..) statement) than a copy should have made in the stack so when return from recursion that precious version of stack along with the top should have been available but this did not happen.

Comment: Your `print(stack<char> st)` is passed a copy of `st`, so the original `st` is still intact when the initial `print` returns. I'd find examples where you only have to work with one concept at a time. Try searching for  "recursive examples".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why don't you store the `st.top()` at variable and print it later.

```
void print(stack<char>st)
{
    if(st.empty())
    {
        return;
    }

    char top = st.top();
    st.pop();
    print(st);

    cout<<top<<endl;
}
```

Let me explain you:-

Suppose, Your stack --> 0, 1

Here, Call Hierarchy

1. `print({0, 1})
    {
       // stack after pop -- {0}
       print({0})
    }`
2. `print({0})
    { 
       // stack after pop -- {}
       print ({}) 
       // here you want to print top of empty stack
       // which gives the exception 
    }`

Comment: Why have you stored top ?

Comment: @behnc because if you don't it is lost in the ether after the pop before the recursion (which is precisely the problem in your code).

Comment: @behnc, see the example at the answer

Comment: Now I got it sir.Consider reverse printing of linked list.we need not to store any data in case of linked list because we are not deleting anything.But in case of stack we do delete by pop.So before we delete we store.Am I right sir ? @WhozCraig

Comment: @behnc `pop` does exactly what its name implies: pops the top element from the stack. If it was the last element, then the stack is then empty. Afterward, invoking `top()` on an empty stack (as your code does) rears your exception. Mahedi's description is both accurate and worth of answer-selection. It describes in-detail what is going wrong.

Answer (score 0):

> pop is function get element to print like reverse

```
 void printStack()
{
   if(!isEmpty())
   {
     int temp = pop();
     printStack();
     printf(" %d ", temp);
     push( temp);
   }
}

int pop() 
{
  if (isEmpty())
    printf("Stack is Empty...\n");
  else {
      st.top = st.top - 1;
      return st.array[st.top+1];
   }
}
```